# R XLSX and XLConnect packages - Formatting the workbood object created by XLConnect using xlsx package?

Tags: r, xlconnect, r-xlsx

I have written a R code to create excel workbook and added the data to it using XLConnect package.

```
wb <- XLConnect::loadWorkbook(Name,create = TRUE)
```

and added some data frame to this file. Now, I want to access this XLConnect object wb from xlsx package and do some formatting like adding a border, font, wraptext and alignment on the dataframe inside the file. Is this possible?

Kindly let me know if anything is unclear or need more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible to use XLConnect and xlsx packages in the same R session or at least not in single package. I am using openxlsx package for formatting the excel file.